# Auditing a map of child entities as values with Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a `Parent` entity that refers a `Child` entity as a value in a map. The key in the map is an enum (see below for straightforward code). Unfortunately using `@AuditJoinTable` with a table name doesn't create the expected "parent_children_aud" table.

Is auditing for map references supported? Or is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Using Hibernate 3.6.0.

Parent class:

```
@Audited
public class Parent {

    private Long id;
    private Integer version;

    private Map<MyEnum, Child> mappedChildren;

    protected Parent() {}

    public Long getId() {
          return this.id;
     }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @AuditJoinTable(name = "parent_children_aud")
    public Map<MyEnum, Child> getMappedChildren() {
        return this.mappedChildren;
    }

    public void setMappedChildren(Map<MyEnum, TemplateStage> mappedChildren) {
        this.mappedChildren = mappedChildren;
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
@Audited
public class Child {

    private Long id;

    protected Child() {}

    public Long getId() {
          return this.id;
     }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

MyEnum:

```
public enum MyEnum { AAA, BBB, CCC; }
```

hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        -//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN
        http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd>

<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="Parent" table="parents">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <version name="version" unsaved-value="negative"/>

        <map name="mappedChildren" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
            <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <key column="parent_id"/>
            <map-key type="MyEnum"/>
            <one-to-many class="Child"/>
        </map>

    </class>

    <class name="Child" table="children">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <version name="version" unsaved-value="negative"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Are any tables created? Does auditing work? Or do you get exceptions?

Comment: all other audit tables are created (I have many of those :)). No exceptions...

Comment: And if you comment out the AuditJoinTable, is a table for that association created? Or is it silently ignored?

Comment: what are the fields in AuditJoinTable: parent_children_aud ?